# mod_rewrite for a WordPress page doesn't seem to work

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a WordPress site and a custom site and send a user from the WordPress site to the custom site when they navigate to a specific URL. Let’s say the main WP site is located at  www.example.com. If someone goes to http://example.com/p/M12345, we want to send it to https://my.example.com/myexample/members/login.html?login=M12345. I thought the best way to do this would be to use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess file

I tried setting this up the main .htaccess file, but nothing seemed to work. The WP site at www.example.com uses a redirect plugin which normally takes care of this, but last week it messed up our entire site, so I am reluctant to continue using it. I would like to use the .htaccess file since this feels like the correct way to do it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(\/p\/)([mM]\d{5})$ https://my.example.com/myexample/members/login.html?login=$2 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

A few things we have tried:

- adding flags such as [NC,R=301,L], [L,QSA] and others
- changed RewriteRule to Redirect 301 and removed the flags
- added RewriteCond ^(/p/)$ thinking this would only occur on the example.com/p/ pages

What is the correct way to get this working?

Comment: Never test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leading slash isn't matched in .htaccess and there is en extra `[` before `p`.  Also there is no need to escape `/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^p/([mM]\d{5})/?$ https://my.example.com/myexample/members/login.html?login=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Whoops - the "[" was a typo. That wasn't in my normal rule (i changed it to make more sense in the question than my actual use-case). Anyway- I wasn't aware that the leading slash wasn't matched. After removing that, everything works fine.

Thanks! I hate it when something so small and stupid messes up your whole day.